# Not "window" and not "window.innerHeight" but

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where I have a HEADER element, then a MAIN element, and then a FOOTER element. I want the HEADER and MAIN elements to take up whatever height they naturally take up, and then for the FOOTER to take up the remaining browser height (without creating a scroll) assuming there is any remaining browser height. But when I check browser height with either "window" or "window.innerHeight" and then subtract the HEADER height and MAIN height to get the FOOTER's height the FOOTER's height ends up being higher than it seems it should be and creates a scroll. Here's the scripting I have in place now:

```
if (window.innerHeight > $('HEADER').height() + $('MAIN').height() + $('FOOTER').height()) {
    $('FOOTER').height(
        window.innerHeight - ($('HEADER').height() + $('MAIN').height())
    );
}
```

The staging site is proprietary, so hopefully someone will see the flaw in my code without needing to see the site.

Comment: is there a border or padding used for the header or main

Comment: if your body or any of these elements has a padding/margin/border it could affect the calculation - see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cajpsdp7/1/) & [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cajpsdp7/2/)(jsfiddle gives a default margin of 8px to body)

Comment: All the elements are set to "box-sizing: border-box" so it seems like padding shouldn't matter. Or maybe that's when it does matter in a case like this?

Comment: can you edit the attached jsfiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: Thanks, Arun. When I remove all top and bottom padding for these elements the problem corrects itself. So I guess the calculations to figure out the FOOTER height have to total up all the padding that is present and then get that amount subtracted from the height my scripting is setting the FOOTER to now.

I have edited your first fiddle to include the padding that is in my project: http://jsfiddle.net/5yxfn507/

Comment: Arun, Have you been able to get it to work once the padding is added in?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62800/room-for-arun-p-johny-and-christian-ziebarth

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the box model...

so try

```
footer {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    padding-top: 1.4em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then

```
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
    header = $('HEADER').outerHeight(),
    main = $('MAIN').outerHeight(),
    footer = $('FOOTER').height();
if (windowHeight > header + main + footer) {
    $('FOOTER').css('height', windowHeight - (header + main));
}
```